# Why does pandoc remove .incremental from divs?

Tags: pandoc, slidy

I want to make incremental `div` elements, but pandoc is stripping out the `incremental` class name from them:

```
$ echo '<div class="incremental">hello</div>' | pandoc -f markdown -t slidy
<div class="slide section level6">

<div>
hello
</div>
</div>
```

This doesn't happen with `p` elements:

```
$ echo '<p class="incremental">hello</p>' | pandoc -f markdown -t slidy
<div class="slide section level6">

<p class="incremental">
hello
</p>
</div>
```

Nor does it happen with non-`incremental` class names:

```
$ echo '<div class="foo">hello</div>' | pandoc -f markdown -t slidy
<div class="slide section level6">

<div class="foo">
hello
</div>
</div>
```

This worked when I generated these slides five years ago, but it's not working anymore (pandoc 2.2.1).  Was this considered an anti-pattern?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that newer pandoc versions have a [native div](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) element in their internal document AST, which is handled slightly differently.

You can get back the old behaviour with:

```
pandoc -f markdown-native_divs
```

But what you'd probably want to do is also use the native div syntax. See also https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#incremental-lists

```
::: incremental

- Eat spaghetti
- Drink wine

:::
```

Comment: When using the native div syntax, the `<ul>` gets an `incremental` class, but the enclosing `<div>` does not.  Nor do other elements within it, such as `<p>`.  The docs indicate that most elements can be made incremental, but this looks like it's reserved for `<ul>`.  Can I use a native div to make everything within it incremental?

Comment: yeah... I think using plain pandoc it's only `ul` and `ol`...